# mongo --eval command not evaluated when used through a Python script

Tags: python, bash, mongodb

When I run this command from a bash terminal, I got the expected result:

```
$ mongo --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames()"
> MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
> connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
> MongoDB server version: 3.4.2
> [ "admin", "local" ]
```

I need to run this command from a Python script. This is what I wrote:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['mongo', '--eval', '\"db.getMongo().getDBNames()\"']
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
print(result)
```

This is the result when running this script:

```
$ python3 log.py
> b'MongoDB shell version v3.4.2\nconnecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017\nMongoDB server version: 3.4.2\ndb.getMongo().getDBNames()\n'
```

As you can see, it's almost the same thing except the original command `db.getMongo().getDBNames()` is displayed instead of the expected result `[ "admin", "local" ]`.

Is there an error in my script or is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Let me explain - by default [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) has a default value `shell=False`, hence the reason it escapes the command on it's own.

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['mongo', '--eval', 'db.getMongo().getDBNames()']
result = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
print(result)
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, thanks! Though, I'm not 100% sure about what happened here.